# My program, when run, only returns with '[ ]' and I need it to return data from an info table from a website

Tags: python-3.x, email, web-scraping, updates

Im trying to create a web scraping program that scrapes a web-page that has an information table on every 5mins or so. If the web-page is different/ been updated it should create the new one as original and send an email to notify an update. Heres my code so far:

```
import urllib           
import urllib.request as request            
import re

totalurl = "https://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php/piracy-reporting-centre/live-piracy-report"           
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl)         
htmltext = htmlfile.read()          
regex = '<div class="fabrikDataContainer">...</div>'            
pattern = re.compile(regex)         
with urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl) as response:          
    html = htmltext.decode()            

num = re.findall(pattern, html)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not actually an option in web-scraping. You can use, for example, [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html) as below:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
from lxml import html

totalurl = "https://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php/piracy-reporting-centre/live-piracy-report"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
source = html.fromstring(htmltext.decode())
num = source.xpath('//div[@class="fabrikDataContainer"]')
print(num[0].text_content())
```

The output is complete text content of table. You can implement more complex selector to get specific data

Comment: thanks for that but I get the following error:   <br/>  **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kieronblemings/Desktop/Web scraping /table scrape.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lxml import html
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'**

Comment: Try `pip install lxml`

Comment: It says **install** is an invalid syntax @Andersson

Comment: You should execute `pip install lxml` from command line/Terminal

Comment: I have, it still says its an invalid syntax, I'm running idle 3.4 on my MacBook Pro if that helps? @Andersson

Comment: Just install `lxml` according to [provided link](http://lxml.de/installation.html)